# Which of the following molecules are enantiomers?

Tags: stereochemistry

My book says that only molecule 7 is enantiomer of molecule 1. Why is this? Why can't molecule 1 and 2 be enantiomers?

[image: Structures]

Comment: Please use the built-in image uploader - we even have a special server for the images! 1 and 2 are certainly *not* enantiomers. Only one chiral centre out of three differs in configuration. Mirror images should have opposite configurations for *all* chiral centres, as you cannot reflect one chiral centre without reflecting the other two.

Comment: How about 1 and 7? Isnt there also just one different chiral centre (carbon attached to chlorine)?

Comment: Ooh... my earlier explanation isn't the best, I apologise. The issue is that those apparently chiral centres on the cyclohexane ring aren't truly chiral. Maybe the best way to see it is if you rotate the cyclohexane ring by 180° along a vertical axis. You'll find that the CH2OH at the top, which was originally pointing below the plane, is now coming out of the plane - an apparent "inversion" of configuration, but you haven't actually reflected it. Therefore the absolute configuration at these centres doesn't matter (but the relative configuration, cis/trans, does).

Comment: one note: 5 and 7 are identical

Comment: Using orthocresol's suggestion, try 1 and 5 are identical. Either one is the mirror image of 7. Structures 2, 3, 4 and 6 have no enantiomers present.

Comment: 1 and 2 enantiomers? Maybe you confuse enantiomers with diastereomers and/or epimers.